# Django URL pattern not appearing in production, page not found

Tags: python, django, url, routes, urlconf

## Problem

I've created a url pattern for an agencies page, which works fine locally, but does not when the project is pushed to production. When trying to debug the error, the url pattern does not appear on the 404 page `url(r'^agencies/$', views.agencies, name='agencies')`

## _home.html

```
 <div class="cards">
                <a href="agencies/">
                <div class="card card--earners">
                    <img src="{% static 'salaries/img/building.png' %}" class="card__icon">
                    <p class="card__title">Agencies</p>
                    <p class="card__desc">Find salary information for public safety workers, government employees and elected officials.</p>
                </div>
                </a>

                <a href="teachers/">
                <div class="card card--salary">
                    <img src="{% static 'salaries/img/school.png' %}" class="card__icon">
                    <p class="card__title">Schools</p>
                    <p class="card__desc">Find salary information for superintendents, principals and teachers in Missouri public schools.</p>
                </div>
                </a>
            </div>
```

### Page not found

```
Using the URLconf defined in payrolls.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^salaries/ ^$ [name='home']
^salaries/ ^(?P<agency_id>[0-9]+)/$ [name='agency']
^salaries/ ^(?P<department_id>[0-9]+_[0-9]+)/$ [name='department']
^salaries/ ^(?P<agency_id>[0-9]+)/agency_search/$ [name='agency_search']
^salaries/ ^master_search/$ [name='master_search']
^salaries/ ^teachers/$ [name='teachers']
^salaries/ ^teachers/(?P<district_id>[0-9]+)/$ [name='district']
^salaries/ ^teachers/(?P<district_code>[0-9]+)/(?P<school_code>[0-9]+)/$ [name='school']
^salaries/ ^teachers/(?P<district_code>[0-9]+)/position/(?P<position_code>[0-9]+)/$ [name='dist_position']
^salaries/ ^teachers/(?P<district_code>[0-9]+)/(?P<school_code>[0-9]+)/position/(?P<position_code>[0-9]+)/$ [name='school_position']
^salaries/ ^educator_search/$ [name='educator_search']
^salaries/ ^teachers/(?P<district_id>[0-9]+)/district_search/$ [name='district_search']
^salaries/ ^teachers/detail/(?P<teacher_id>[0-9]+)/$ [name='person']
^admin/
The current URL, salaries/agencies/, didn't match any of these.
```

### urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from salaries import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^(?P<agency_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.agency, name='agency'),
    url(r'^(?P<department_id>[0-9]+_[0-9]+)/$', views.department, name='department'),
    url(r'^(?P<agency_id>[0-9]+)/agency_search/$', views.agency_search, name='agency_search'),
    url(r'^master_search/$', views.master_search, name='master_search'),
    url(r'^teachers/$', views.teachers, name='teachers'),
    url(r'^teachers/(?P<district_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.district, name='district'),
    url(r'^teachers/(?P<district_code>[0-9]+)/(?P<school_code>[0-9]+)/$', views.school, name='school'),
    url(r'^teachers/(?P<district_code>[0-9]+)/position/(?P<position_code>[0-9]+)/$', views.dist_position, name='dist_position'),
    url(r'^teachers/(?P<district_code>[0-9]+)/(?P<school_code>[0-9]+)/position/(?P<position_code>[0-9]+)/$', views.school_position, name='school_position'),
    url(r'^educator_search/$', views.educator_search, name='educator_search'),
    url(r'^teachers/(?P<district_id>[0-9]+)/district_search/$', views.district_search, name='district_search'),
    url(r'^teachers/detail/(?P<teacher_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.person, name='person'),
    url(r'^agencies/$', views.agencies, name='agencies'),
]
```

### views.py

```
def agencies(request):
    agency_list = Agency.objects.all().order_by('-headcount')

    top_earners = []

    for agency in agency_list:

        top_earners.append(Employee.objects.filter(agency_unique=agency.id).order_by("-salary")[0])

    context = {'agencies': agency_list, 'top_earners': top_earners}

    return render(request, 'salaries/agencies.html', context)
```

Comment: Make sure that the urls.py has definitely been updated in production, and that your server has been restarted after the code was updated.

Comment: There isn't a generic way to restart the server, it depends how you have deployed Django.